# Minimum non-combustable mantel height then TV over fireplace

Tags: mounting, television

What is the minimum non-combustable mantel height over a flush mount linear fireplace. Then what is the minimum aditional height to the bottom of an off the wall momounted  TV?

I have a family room with vaulted 12' ceiling and framed fire box with venting 3' deep and 6' high. I'd like to think I could mount a 1" thick granite mantel 3" above the top of the glass viewing height. Perhaps a mantel protruding enough to cover the bottom of the TV. Then I'd like to mount the bottom of the TV another 3" above the mantel. Does this work?

Comment: The manual will tell you the combustible distance you need to be clear. It also depends on whether the unit is vented or vent free.

Comment: Over fireplace us unfortunately one of the worst places for a TV in terms of keeping it running well -- heat and smoke tend not to be good for electronics.

Comment: The unit is vented.